# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'visits'

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cookies

I'm going through udacity's CS253 and learning about cookies and hashing now. In this I have to get a cookie from the response and check whether it matches the one which is true. This is my code

```
self.response.headers['Content-type'] = 'text/plain'
visits = 0
visit_cookie_str = self.request.cookies.get('visits')
  if visit_cookie_str:
      cookie_val = check_secure_val(visit_cookie_str)
      if cookie_val:
          visits = int(cookie_val)
```

But when I run this on the appserver I get the following error:

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'visits'
```

I looked up what that error means, I've gone through a lot of questions asked on the same error here but I have yet to understand why my code is showing this error because I have already declared visits as an int.

These are the functions that create and check the hashes

```
def hash_str(s):
    return hashlib.md5(s).hexdigest()

def make_secure_val(s):
    return "%s|%s" % (s, hash_str(s))

def check_secure_val(h):
    val = h.split('|')[0]
    if h == make_secure_val(val):
        return val
```

I also checked whether the function check_secure_val is returning an string or not using

```
print check_secure_val("10|d3d9446802a44259755d38e6d163e820").isdigit()
```

Thanks

EDIT: The code that sets the cookie is

```
new_cookie_val = make_secure_val(str(visits))
self.response.headers.add_header('Set-Cookie', 'visits=%s' % new_cookie_val)
```

The make_secure_val function returns a string in the form (string, HASH).

All in all the entire code for the get function is this

```python
def get(self):
    self.response.headers['Content-type'] = 'text/plain'

    visits = 0

    visit_cookie_str = self.request.cookies.get('visits')
    if visit_cookie_str:
        cookie_val = check_secure_val(visit_cookie_str)
        if cookie_val:
            visits = int(cookie_val)
    visits += 1
    new_cookie_val = make_secure_val(str(visits))
    self.response.headers.add_header('Set-Cookie', 'visits=%s' % new_cookie_val)

    if visits > 100:
        self.write("You're the best ever !")
    else:
        self.write("You've been here %s times" % visits)
```

Comment: What the error message means: `cookie_val` is set to the string `'visits'`. *Why* it is set to that string remains for you to find out; the browser sent you that value.

Comment: What code *sets* the cookie?

Comment: Then the next question is what `visits` is set to when you set `new_cookie_val`..

Comment: @MartijnPieters `visits` is set to the value of `new_cookie_val` by `self.response.headers.add_header('Set-Cookie', 'visits=%s' % new_cookie_val)`

Comment: @MartijnPieters I got it working, but I have no idea how. I just loaded up the devserver again today and it's working without a hitch. Sadly I have no Idea as to how it is working now since, it is exactly the same as I left it. I guess it might have been an identation error but I'm dobtful.